# Function won't return value back to main function

Tags: python

Here is my code, I have to send 'var1 and 'var2' into greater_then function from main(), then send the return back to be printed in the main function. The go again is kind of in the way but I have to have it in the main() and not its own.

The code doesn't run correctly right now because of the `while playing`, first I would like to know how to have the greater_then() return the string assigned to it.

```
playing = True
while playing:
    def main():
        var1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
        var2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))


        num1 = float(var1)  
        num2 = float(var2)

        quotient = (num1 / num2)
        print("\nThe quotient is: %.2f" % quotient);

        message = quotient / 5;

        if message == 15:
            print("\nYour quotient is equal to 15.");
    
        elif message > 15: 
            print("\nYour quotient divided by 5, is greater then 15.");
    
        else:
            print("\nYour quotient divided by 5, is less then 15.\n");

        print("\nYour quotient is: %.2f" % message);
        return var1, var2
        greater_then()


    while True:
        choice = input("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):")
        if 'y' in choice or 'Y' in choice:
            print("\nGoing Again!");
            break
        elif 'n' in choice or 'N' in choice:
            print("\nGoodbye");
            playing = False
            break
        else:
            print("\nInvalid");
            continue
       
def greater_then():
    var1, var2 = main()
    var3 = var2/var1
    var4 = var3/5
    if var4 > 15:
        return "The quoitent is greater then 15"
    elif var4 < 15:
        return("The quoitent is less then 15")
    else:
        return ("The quotient is equal to 15")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Clean up your block inclusion: repeatedly defining your main function is bad design.  Remove the superfluous code.  Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you define functions and declare the input parameters as follows:

```
def function_name(input_param1, input_param2):
```

Use the return command to send back the return value to the caller.

```
return someresult
```

Here is how you would call the above function and store the returned value

```
returned_value = function_name(1, 2)
```

Below is your code revised to call the function correctly and capture it's return value.  It's also revised to fix some of the inconsistent loops.

```
def main():

    playing = True
    while playing:
        var1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
        var2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))


        num1 = float(var1)  
        num2 = float(var2)

        quotient = (num1 / num2)
        print("\nThe quotient is: %.2f" % quotient)
        returned_string = greater_then(num1, num2)
        print (returned_string)


        while True:
            choice = input("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):")
            if 'y' in choice or 'Y' in choice:
                print("\nGoing Again!")
                break
            elif 'n' in choice or 'N' in choice:
                print("\nGoodbye")
                playing = False
                break
            else:
                print("\nInvalid")
                continue
       
def greater_then(var1, var2):
    
    var3 = var2/var1
    var4 = var3/5
    if var4 > 15:
        return "The quoitent is greater then 15"
    elif var4 < 15:
        return("The quoitent is less then 15")
    else:
        return ("The quotient is equal to 15")

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of things is all wrong.  If you want to pass parameters to a function, then you pass them as parameters.  I also fixed your spelling problems and eliminated the useless trailing semicolons:

```
playing = True
def main():
    num1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))

    quotient = (num1 / num2)
    print("\nThe quotient is: %.2f" % quotient)

    message = quotient / 5

    if message == 15:
        print("\nYour quotient is equal to 15.")

    elif message > 15: 
        print("\nYour quotient divided by 5, is greater then 15.")

    else:
        print("\nYour quotient divided by 5, is less then 15.\n")

    print("\nYour quotient is: %.2f" % message)
    print( greater_than(var1, var2) )

    while True:
        choice = input("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):")
        if 'y' in choice or 'Y' in choice:
            print("\nGoing Again!")
            break
        elif 'n' in choice or 'N' in choice:
            print("\nGoodbye")
            playing = False
            break
        else:
            print("\nInvalid")
            continue
       
def greater_than(var1, var2):
    var3 = var2/var1
    var4 = var3/5
    if var4 > 15:
        return "The quotient  is greater then 15"
    elif var4 < 15:
        return "The quotient is less then 15"
    else
        return "The quotient is equal to 15"
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```